# Missing Projects Icon from Activity Bar (Database Projects installed)

Tags: azure, azure-data-studio

The issue:
The projects icon simply disappeard from activity bar and I m not able to create projects from database anymore.

History:
After installed database projects and schema compare, I did some tasks and all was working fine, but I end up disabling some feature that I should keep enabled.
Then I uninstalled and reinstalled it again, but It didn't work unfotunately.

Enviroment:
Windows 10, dotnet-sdk-3.1.425-win-x64, Azure Data Studio 1.41.1, database projects and schema compare extensions

The ask:
Where I can setting up the activity bar and recover this feature?

Thanks in advance!!

I tried reinstall it, but the issue remains the same.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please right click on the Activity Bar on the left, you can select 'Database Projects' to add back to the Activity Bar. Hope that helps.

[image]